# how to pass data between two kendo UI window controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two kendo UI window controls. First (parent) window to get the customer details, along with search button. Second (child) window to search the customer using customer firstname, lastname etc..

Search result will shown in grid control of child window, like

> Title FirstName LastName Address1 Subrub
>   Mr John Karter Goyal garden, NSW
>   Miss Emile Watson Garden brown, VC

If i choose any customer in the grid, i need to populate the customer details in the corresponding controls of first (parent) window. So i call js function on change event as below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<OnlineABThemes.Data.GetCustomers_Result>)ViewData["CustomerSearchGrid"])
    .Name("ChildWindowCustomerGrid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Width(60);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Address1).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Suburb).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(p => p.State).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PostCode).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Phone).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Mobile).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Email).Width(120);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Server()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.ID))
)
.Selectable(s=>s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
.Events(events => events.Change("CustomerChanged"))
)
```

Here is my js function

```
function CustomerChanged() {
    var grid = $('#ChildWindowCustomerGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    var customerID = grid.select("ID");

    $.ajax({<br>
        url: "/Customer/GetCustomer",
        type: "POST",
        data: { customerId: customerID }
    })

    $("#childWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
    .fail(function (r, o) {
        alert("Failed : " + r.responseText);
    });
}
```

I unable to get the customerID and how to fill the customer details which is in First (parent) window. ie,l how to fill customer details by passing customerID from one window to another window.

thanks
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I entirely follow your code, but this may be helpful.  The Kendo window control operates in two modes: 1) by loading another URL in an iframe, and 2) by loading content in a div that just looks like a window.  If you're working with the first scenario, you can pass back the customer id by calling `window.opener`, `window.parent` or `window.top` (depending on what you're trying to do) and getting a reference to the parent window that way.  If you're working in the second scenario, you could use some kind of view model for storing your current selection that's accessible across all windows.  Maybe this will spark some ideas, but if you post a bit more of your code, I can probably get more specific about a solution.